# How do I add spacing between columns with pictures as background in a table

Tags: html, css

I want to have 2 buttons centered in the middle that have a picture as background. For that I have placed them in a table. 
I have seen some ways to add some space in between them but none seem to work here because of the background.

Here is my page so far: https://jsfiddle.net/uLhc10zk/1/

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 300px;
}

#close-CSS {
  background-image: url("https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/DdytqdFTgtQuxVrHLDdmjQ--~B/aD03MTY7dz0xMDgwO3NtPTE7YXBwaWQ9eXRhY2h5b24-/https://media-mbst-pub-ue1.s3.amazonaws.com/creatr-uploaded-images/2019-11/7b5b5330-112b-11ea-a77f-7c019be7ecae");
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<center>Test Page</center>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="close-CSS" ; onclick="window.location.href = 'about:blank';">Site1</button>
  <button id="close-CSS" ; onclick="window.location.href = 'about:blank';">Site2</button>
</div>
```

what I want is something like this

[image]

also, is there a way to get rid of the border around the pictures?

Please go easy on me, I am a complete beginner

Comment: what you tried ?     margin-right: 13px; it works

Answer (score 4):

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 300px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 15px;
}
    
#close-CSS {
  background-image: url( "https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/DdytqdFTgtQuxVrHLDdmjQ--~B/aD03MTY7dz0xMDgwO3NtPTE7YXBwaWQ9eXRhY2h5b24-/https://media-mbst-pub-ue1.s3.amazonaws.com/creatr-uploaded-images/2019-11/7b5b5330-112b-11ea-a77f-7c019be7ecae" );
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  height: 300px;  
  width: 300px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<center>Test Page</center>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="close-CSS"; onclick="window.location.href = 'about:blank';">Site1</button>
  <button id="close-CSS"; onclick="window.location.href = 'about:blank';">Site2</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps